# git: re-merge single file while ignoring line endings

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a `git merge` with many conflicts. For one individual file, I'd like to re-merge it while ignoring line endings.

Put another way: I'd like to run `git checkout -m file` with the behavior of `git merge -Xignore-space-at-eol`. Is this possible?

Comment: One way would be to run `git merge -Xignore-space-at-eol`, then commit the result, `reset --hard` and merge again. Then I could just `git checkout` files from the first merge during conflict resolution. But usually I realize I want a file merged with `-Xignore-space-at-eol` halfway through conflict resolution.

Comment: I think the question is not clear. I would ask you: Do you need to keep the file i question with different EOL formats on each branch? That's something you should avoid because otherwise you will be getting conflicts _every single time you try to merge when there is even a small change on the file on the other branch_.

Comment: Whatever `git merge -Xignore-space-at-eol` does is fine. It is easy to convert EOLs after conflict resolution.